# on vb/vba .passing variables as arguments to an object property like .rows

Tags: variables, object, properties, arguments, rows

I want to use the following piece of code but it won't let me, the error: "expected: list separator or )":

```
a = 1: b = 13
activesheet.rows(a:b)
```

why can't I pass the a and b variables to the property like for example: `activesheet.rows("1:3")`.- when I use the "a:b" format it gives me "run-time error 1004" application defined ot object defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a string containing the values of `a` and `b`.

```
ActiveSheet.Rows(CStr(a) & ":" & CStr(b))
```

Comment: yes! very helpfull, but I didn't use the CStr coerce function because I don't understand why I need it. instead I used: ActiveSheet.rows(a & ":" & b) and that did the job.

Comment: @user: If  `a` and `b` aren't strings, you should use `CStr` to convert them to strings.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Range method:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Rows(a), ActiveSheet.Rows(b))
```